# Created a method to calculate Team with most wins and winning percentage

Tags: java, class, linked-list

I'm learning how to utilize Linked lists in my second semester Java class. For our program we are supposed to code a class encapsulating the idea of football teams with wins and losses.

The part I need help on is creating a method that returns the nicknames of the 3 teams with the most wins and another that returns the five best teams based on winning percentages.

Team Class

```
public class Team
{
    private int GamesWon;
    private int GamesLost;
    private String Team;

    public Team (int i, int j, String k)
    {
        GamesWon = i;
        GamesLost = j;
        Team = k;
    }

    public int getGamesWon()
    {
        return GamesWon;
    }
    public int getGamesLost()
    {
        return GamesLost;
    }
    public String getTeam()
    {
        return Team;
    }
    public void setGamesWon(int i)
    {
        GamesWon = i;
    }
    public void setGamesLost(int j)
    {
        GamesLost = j;
    }
    public void setTeam(String k)
    {
        Team = k;
    }
    public String toString()
    {
        return("Team: " + Team + "\tGamesWon: " + GamesWon + "\tGamesLost: " + GamesLost);
    }
}
```

TeamNode Class

```
public class TeamNode 
{
    private Team team;
    private TeamNode next;

public TeamNode()
{
    team = null;
    next = null;
}

public TeamNode(Team t)
{
    setTeam(t);
    next = null;
}


public Team getTeam()
{
    return team;
}

public TeamNode getNext()
{
    return next;
}

public void setTeam(Team t)
{
    team = t;
}

public void setNext(TeamNode tn)
{
    next = tn;
}



}
```

ShellLinkedList

```
public abstract class ShellLinkedList
{
    protected TeamNode head;
    protected int numberOfItems;

public ShellLinkedList()
{
    head = null;
    numberOfItems = 0;
}

public int getNumberOfItems()
{
    return numberOfItems;
}

public boolean isEmpty()
{
    return (numberOfItems == 0);
}
public String toString()
{
    String listString = "";
    TeamNode current = head;
    while (current != null)
    {
        listString += current.getTeam().toString() + "\n";
    current = current.getNext();
    }
    return listString;
}

}
```

DataStructureExcetion(error class)

```
public class DataStructureException extends Exception
{
public DataStructureException(String s)
{
    super(s);
}
}
```

Team linked list class

```
public class TeamLinkedList extends ShellLinkedList
{
public TeamLinkedList()
{
    super();
}
public void insert(Team t)
{
    TeamNode tn = new TeamNode(t);
    tn.setNext(head);
    head = tn;
    numberOfItems++;
}
public Team delete(String searchName)
                        throws DataStructureException
{
    TeamNode current = head;
    TeamNode previous = null;
    while (current != null && current.getTeam().getTeam() != searchName)
    {
        previous = current;
        current = current.getNext();
    }

    if (current == null)
        throw new DataStructureException(searchName + " not found: cannot be deleted");
    else
    {
        if (current == head)
            head = head.getNext();
        else
            previous.setNext(current.getNext());
            numberOfItems--;
        return current.getTeam();
    }
}
}
```

Client class

```
public class TeamLinkedListTest 
{
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {

        Team t1 = new Team (10, 0, "Patriots" );
        Team t2 = new Team (9, 1, "49ners");
        Team t3 = new Team (8, 2, "Chargers");
        Team t4 = new Team (7, 3, "Bengals");
        Team t5 = new Team (6, 4,"Jets");
        Team t6 = new Team (5, 5, "Raiders");
        Team t7 = new Team (4, 6, "Seahawks");
        Team t8 = new Team (3, 7, "Cardinals");
        Team t9 = new Team (2, 8, "Texans");
        Team t10 = new Team(1, 9, "Dolphins");

        TeamLinkedList Team = new TeamLinkedList();
        System.out.println("Number of items in the list: " + Team.getNumberOfItems() + "\n" + Team.toString());

        Team.insert(t1);
        System.out.println("Number of items in the list: " + Team.getNumberOfItems() + "\n" + Team.toString());

        Team.insert(t2);
        System.out.println("Number of items in the list: " + Team.getNumberOfItems() + "\n" + Team.toString());

        Team.insert(t3);
        System.out.println("Number of items in the list: " + Team.getNumberOfItems() + "\n" + Team.toString());

        Team temp;

        try
        {
            temp = Team.delete("Bengals");
            System.out.println("Team deleted: " + temp);
        }
        catch(DataStructureException dse1)
        {
            System.out.println(dse1.getMessage() + "\n");
        }

        try
        {
            temp = Team.delete("Patriots");
            System.out.println("Deleted " + temp);
            System.out.println("Number of items in the list: " + Team.getNumberOfItems() + "\n" + Team.toString());

            temp = Team.delete("49ners");
            System.out.println("Deleted " + temp);
            System.out.println("Number of items in the list: " + Team.getNumberOfItems() + "\n" + Team.toString());

            temp = Team.delete("Chargers");
            System.out.println("Deleted " + temp);
            System.out.println("Number of items in the list: " + Team.getNumberOfItems() + "\n" + Team.toString());

            temp = Team.delete("Patriots");
            System.out.println("Deleted " + temp);
            System.out.println("Number of items in the list: " + Team.getNumberOfItems() + "\n" + Team.toString());
        }
        catch(DataStructureException dse2)
        {
            System.out.println(dse2.getMessage());
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: The part I need help on is creating a method that returns the nicknames of the 3 teams with the most wins and another that returns the five best teams based on winning percentages.

Comment: I'm not sure how to code these methods

Comment: Please remove all code which is not important to answer your question. To answer, you just need to go through your linked list, and have an array list or equivalent datastructure to store the best teams. What have you tried to answer your question?

Comment: @JeremyD I am not sure where to begin, as I stated I am brand new to LinkedLists. Which class should I create this method in?

Comment: Looks like homework to me...

Comment: @nhaa123 i mean, I told you it was hw. . .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer. You do it using `Collections.sort`

Long(er) answer. In your Team class you have to override `compareTo` method

```
class Team implements Comparable<Team> {
private gamesWon

//contructor/methods go here

@Override
public int compareTo(Team t) {
    int wins = t.gamesWon;
    if (this.gamesWon > wins) {
        return 1;
    } else if (this.gamesWon == wins) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}
```

After that you call sort method on your linked list like this
`Collections.sort(myLinkedList)`

Finally you can print out first three nodes as they are now sorted